# Misaligned Screen in JCEF (Java Chromium Embedded Framework) Application

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I have a Java 7 application which is using Java Chromium Embedded Framework to draw html/css into two windows it launches. This works quite well in 4 of 5 PCs that I've run it on. In one case there are alignment issues with the rendered html. Successful runs include Windows 7/8/8.1. Unsuccessful run is 8.1 on an [HP TouchSmart Envy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-envy-touchsmart-15-6-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i5-8gb-memory-750gb-hard-drive-natural-silver/5342018.p?id=1219120915962&skuId=5342018), straight out of the box. Perhaps the only distinguishable differences are that this PC is new and that it has a touch screen.

As you can see, the content is shifted upward while being additionally clipped at the right and bottom sides. This is true of both windows that the application opens. What's even stranger is that mouse events (such as the :hover effects on the buttons and click events) are received in their correct position -- clicking about two inches below "Start Presentation" fires the button's click event.

Frankly, I have no idea what to try next on this. I've tried installing and uninstalling graphics-related software, adjusting the screen resolution, adding and removing the second screen, restarting the pc, and updating the onboard graphics driver.

As I have no idea what else could be causing this inconsistency, any advice in troubleshooting this issue would be fantastic.

[image: A Screenshot of the Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this appeared to be related to the way JCEF interacts with system drivers. Going through Windows Update for the first time, restarting, and returning to the device's native resolution solved this issue.